# Example of normal subgroup that contains the commutator group as a proper subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

In my algebra class, we went over the theorem:

> Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup. Then $G/N$ is abelian iff $[G:G]\subseteq N$

The proof we used seemed to imply that the normal subgroup is the commutator. I know that this observation is actually meaningless, an artifact of the exact proof we used, but my professor couldn't think up an example to the contrary, neither could wikipedia, and I would like one.

Just to be clear, by proper, I mean also non-trivial, rather than simply of a smaller cardinality.

Comment: Take $G$ abelian of non-prime order and $N$ any proper nonzero subgroup! of $G$! If you don't like abelian examples, pick any nonabelian group $H$ and consider $G\times H$ and $N\times H$ instead of just $G$ and $N$.

Comment: Notiice that what you want is only written in the title of your question. Make sure that your questions make sense even if you remov their titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often one can find examples by looking at groups of small order. The quaternion group $Q_8=\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$ has commutator subgroup $[Q_8,Q_8]=\{\pm 1\}$. All subgroups of order $4$ contain the commutator subgroup as a proper subgroup; namely $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$, $\{\pm 1,\pm j\}$, and $\{\pm 1,\pm k\}$. Moreover all subgroups of order $4$ are of index $2$, and hence normal subgroups.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting is a group $G$ such that $G^{ab}=G/[G, G]$ has some proper, non-trivial homomorphic image (that is, the abelianisation $G^{ab}$ is not cyclic of prime order). Can you see why this is what you need?

So knowing this, examples can be conjured up easily! For example, $S_3\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ works (why?).